# RabbitMQ trying to connect to localhost

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I have a Spring boot application running on embedded tomcat with rabbit listener which I configure like this

```java
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfiguration {

    public static final String REQUEST_QUEUE = "from-beeline-req";
    public static final String REPLY_QUEUE = "from-beeline-reply";

    @Bean
    public Queue beelineRpcReqQueue() {
        return new Queue(REQUEST_QUEUE);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue beelineRpcReplyQueue() {
        return new Queue(REPLY_QUEUE);
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(RabbitTemplateConfigurer configurer, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate();
        configurer.configure(template, connectionFactory);
        template.setDefaultReceiveQueue(REQUEST_QUEUE);
        template.setReplyAddress(REPLY_QUEUE);
        template.setUseDirectReplyToContainer(false);
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer replyListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueues(beelineRpcReplyQueue());
        container.setMessageListener(rabbitTemplate);
        return container;
    }
}
```

And my `application.yml` file looks like this

```yaml
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: LOG
  rabbitmq:
    host: 172.29.14.45
    port: 5672
    username: guest
    password: guest
    template:
      reply-timeout: 15000

server:
  port: 8888
```

So the main point is I want to connect to Rabbit server located at exact address (172.29.14.45). Created listener container is trying to connect to localhost instead. It ignores rabbit port property as well.

```
2021-02-23 23:04:59.715 [replyListenerContainer-1] INFO  (AbstractConnectionFactory.java:636) - Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2021-02-23 23:05:01.721 [replyListenerContainer-1] ERROR (AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1877) - Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

and continues to restart consumer after that

```
2021-02-23 23:17:49.069 [replyListenerContainer-1] INFO  (SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1428) - Restarting Consumer@2a140ce5: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2021-02-23 23:17:49.069 [replyListenerContainer-1] DEBUG (BlockingQueueConsumer.java:758) - Closing Rabbit Channel: null
2021-02-23 23:17:49.071 [replyListenerContainer-2] INFO  (AbstractConnectionFactory.java:636) - Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
```

What should I do to tell spring to use my host property instead of `localhost`?

Answer (score 0):

I always use the addresses property in the application.properties file

spring.rabbitmq.addresses=amqp://username:password@host:port/vhost

The name of the "virtual host" (or vhost) specifies the namespace for entities (such as exchanges and queues) referred to by the protocol. Note that this is not virtual hosting in the HTTP sense.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html

example:

spring.rabbitmq.addresses=amqp://ihrpsvpp:In4etuiIkgu7FVBr0tr6wYGvGcGyJ9Ja@lion.rmq.cloudamqp.com/ihrpsvpp

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turned out it was a bean refreshing context of the application, what caused autoconfiguration to fail